# Count the frequency of strings in a dataframe R

Tags: r, grepl

I am wanting to count the frequencies of certain strings within a dataframe.

```
strings  <- c("pi","pie","piece","pin","pinned","post")
df <- as.data.frame(strings)
```

I would then like to count the frequency of the strings:

```
counts <- c("pi", "in", "pie", "ie")
```

To give me something like:

```
string  freq
 pi       5
 in       2
 pie      2
 ie       2
```

I have experimented with `grepl` and `table` but I don't see how I can specify the strings I want to search for are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sapply()` to go the `counts` and match every item in `counts` against the `strings` column in `df` using `grepl()` this will return a `logical` vector (`TRUE` if match, `FALSE` if non-match). You can sum this vector up to get the number of matches.

```
sapply(df, function(x) {
  sapply(counts, function(y) {
    sum(grepl(y, x))
  })
})
```

This will return:

```
    strings
pi        5
in        2
pie       2
ie        2
```

Comment: good to hear, thanks! if your question is answered suffieciently, you could accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
colSums(sapply(counts, stringr::str_count, string = df$strings))
 pi  in pie  ie 
  5   2   2   2
```

You can use `adist` from base R:

```
data.frame(counts,freq=rowSums(!adist(counts,strings,partial = T)))
  counts freq
1     pi    5
2     in    2
3    pie    2
4     ie    2
```

If you are comfortable with regular expressions then you can do:

```
 a=sapply(paste0(".*(",counts,").*|.*"),sub,"\\1",strings)
 table(grep("\\w",a,value = T))
 ie  in  pi pie 
  2   2   5   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Frequency table created by `qgrams` from the `stringdist` package

```
library(stringdist)
strings  <- c("pi","pie","piece","pin","pinned","post")
frequency <- data.frame(t(stringdist::qgrams(freq = strings, q = 2)))

   freq
pi    5
po    1
st    1
ie    2
in    2
nn    1
os    1
ne    1
ec    1
ed    1
ce    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution using only base R and tidyverse functions, however it might not be as efficient as other packages that people mentioned.

```
new_df <- data.frame('VarName'=unique(df$VarName), 'Count'=0)

for (row_no in 1:nrow(new_df)) {
    new_df[row_no,'Count'] = df %>%
        filter(VarName==new_df[row_no, 'VarName']) %>%
        nrow()
}
```

All you need to switch out is df and VarName.