# Count word frequency across multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, text, nlp

I have a data frame in R with multiple columns with multi-word text responses, that looks something like this:

```
1a        1b             1c       2a          2b             2c
student   job prospects  money    professors  students       campus
future    career         unsure   my grades   opportunities  university
success   reputation     my job   earnings    courses        unsure
```

I want to be able to count the frequency of words in columns 1a, 1b, and 1c combined, as well as 2a, 2b, and 2b combined.

Currently, I'm using this code to count word frequency in each column individually.

```
data.frame(table(unlist(strsplit(tolower(dat$1a), " "))))
```

Ideally, I want to be able to combine the two sets of columns into just two columns and then use this same code to count word frequency, but I'm open to other options.

The combined columns would look something like this:

```
1              2
student        professors
future         my grades
success        earnings
job prospects  students
career         opportunities
reputation     courses
money          campus
unsure         university
my job         unsure
```

Comment: Hi Katie - welcome to StackOverflow! A small reproducible example would make it much easier for us to help you. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
In R, you can use `dput()` to share your dataframe with us.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count the frequency of strings in a dataframe R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49552174/count-the-frequency-of-strings-in-a-dataframe-r)

Comment: I doubt this is a duplicate of that question, as Katie is asking how to combine multiple columns into fewer columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages. FYI, one should avoid having column names starting with a number. Naming them `a1`, `a2`... would make things easier in the long run.

```
df %>% 
  gather(variable, value) %>% 
  mutate(variable = substr(variable, 1, 1)) %>% 
  mutate(id = ave(variable, variable, FUN = seq_along)) %>%
  spread(variable, value)

  id             1             2
1  1       student    professors
2  2        future     my grades
3  3       success      earnings
4  4 job prospects      students
5  5        career opportunities
6  6    reputation       courses
7  7         money        campus
8  8        unsure    university
9  9        my job        unsure
```

Data -

```
df <- structure(list(`1a` = c("student", "future", "success"), `1b` = c("job prospects", 
"career", "reputation"), `1c` = c("money", "unsure", "my job"
), `2a` = c("professors", "my grades", "earnings"), `2b` = c("students", 
"opportunities", "courses"), `2c` = c("campus", "university", 
"unsure")), .Names = c("1a", "1b", "1c", "2a", "2b", "2c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should avoid column names that start with numbers. That aside, I created a reproducible example of your problem and provided a solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. The `substr()` function inside the `mutate_at` assume your column names follow the [num][char] pattern in your example.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~`1a`, ~`1b`, ~`1c`, ~`2a`, ~`2b`, ~`2c`,
  'student','job prospects', 'mone', 'professor', 'students', 'campus',
  'future', 'career', 'unsure', 'my grades', 'opportunities',  'university',
  'success', 'reputation', 'my job', 'earnings', 'courses', 'unsure'
)

data %>%
  gather(key, value) %>%
  mutate_at('key', substr, 0, 1) %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  select(-id)

# A tibble: 9 x 2
  `1`           `2`          
  <chr>         <chr>        
1 student       professor    
2 future        my grades    
3 success       earnings     
4 job prospects students     
5 career        opportunities
6 reputation    courses      
7 mone          campus       
8 unsure        university   
9 my job        unsure
```

Comment: Thanks, the end result you have here is exactly what I am looking for. I'm not familiar with tidyr or dplyr, and am having difficulty following the code and understanding how this works. Could you provide additional information?

Comment: Please accept this answer by clicking the check mark so that it helps other people in the future. [This post](https://blog.rstudio.com/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/) explains what is going on with `gather()` and `spread()`. If you start with the first 2 lines and run subsequently longer chunks of the code you should see the effect each function has on the data. To really understand what is going on I suggest [this book](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/).

Answer (score 0):

If your end purpose is to count frequency (as opposed to switching from wide to long format), you could do

```
ave(unlist(df[,paste0("a",1:3)]), unlist(df[,paste0("a",1:3)]), FUN = length)
```

which will count the frequency of the elements of columns `a1,a2,a3`, where `df` denotes the data frame (and the columns are labeled `a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3`).